# I met some problems using Matrial ui icons

Tags: material-ui

I was using material UI with react in my project, and ÷ have some troubles when it come to import the material icons, ÷ already install

```
 "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.48",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
```

but for some reason i got this error
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Menu'
i don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of material-ui is packaged as `mui`. So instead of `@material-ui/icons:...` you need `@mui/icons-material:...` to be installed in package.json. Same goes with all other material-ui packages.

Answer (score -1):

Material UI has been recently updated to v5.0.1 and the package names/ packages has been changed to `mui`
You can access the v4 here - https://v4.mui.com/